# Computations of a counterexample in order to check that the sum and product of closed operators are not always closed

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

While I was studying functional analysis I found in the script the following counterexample:

Let $X = l^1$ and consider the linear operator
$$ (Ax)_n\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
   n x_{n-1}     & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
   0 & \text{if $n$ is odd}
        \end{array}
      \right.$$
and let $D(A) := \{x ∈ l^1: Ax ∈ l^1\}.$ It is easy to see that $A$ is closed.

However, $B := A + (−A) = 0$ with $D(B) = D(A)$ and $C := AA = 0$ with $D(C) = D(A)$ are not closed.

My question is how one can check this. It is said that $D(A)$ is dense in $l^1$ (and therefore if $B$ or $C$ are closed, $D(A)$ must be also closed which is a contradiction), but I don't know how $D(A)$ looks like or how can I prove its density in $l^1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D(A)=\{(x_n) \in \ell^{1}:\sum |2nx_{2n-1}| <\infty\}$. Every sequence $(y_n)$ with the property that only finite number of $y_n$'s are non zero is on $D(A)$ do $D(A)$ is dense.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you for your help!